# Using FOREACH Loop to iterate through a folder

Tags: sql, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I have a folder called File System Task Folder containing files in it. I created a FOREACH Loop container to iterate through each file. 
I created a Dynamic Flat file connection which has a variable called EmployeeFile_Name. 
I place a Data Flow Task in the ForEach Loop Container, but the dynamic flat file connection does not seem to work. 
[the error when I run the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOgbT.png) and [my data flow task's error when running the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQLUB.png)

Comment: Are you creating the variable from the _For Each Loop_ editor? I've never done it that way. I suggest you create the variable from the actual variable screen (SSIS / Variables), then you'll actually see it in front of your eyes when created

Comment: ok...but can the scoop be within the For Each Loop? Instead of the Package?

Comment: when I try to place the Data Flow Task within the For Each Loop...it is showing error.

Comment: I recommend that you just leave all variables at package scopes. Otherwise it just gets really confusing. So did you solve your original quesion about using your variable inside the For Each? Please note that "it is showing error" means nothing. If you want help you need to describe what you did and what the error is.

Comment: the error is that the dynamic flat file connection is not storing any values to the output table. There are no values coming from the folder.

Comment: I'm not sure but this doesn't seem to resemble your original question. Progressively debugging by comments really doesn't work for anyone, especially when the comments have no specifics in them.

Comment: This seems like an example of The XY Problem (http://xyproblem.info/). @AnnaSojan I would recommend that you edit your question to explain what it is you're trying to accomplish with your package, how you're trying to do that, and what specific errors or messages you receive.